# SwiftUI ForEach Type '_' has no member 'id'

Tags: swiftui

When I use a custom view in a `ForEach` I get Type '_' has no member 'id' error. When I use `Text(item.x)` instead of the custom view it compiles and works. What am I missing?

```
@State private var showTargets = [
    (id: 1, state: false, x: 109.28, y: 109.28),
    (id: 2, state: false, x: 683, y: 109.28),
    (id: 3, state: false, x: 1256.72, y: 109.28)
]
```

...

```
var body: some View {
    Group {

        ForEach(showTargets, id: \.id) { item in
            Text(String(item.x))
            // Using CustomView(x: item.x, y: item.y, f: {}) instead does not work
        }
}
```

Custom View:

```
struct CustomView : View {

    @State private var color = Color.white
    @State private var animate = false


    internal var x: CGFloat
    internal var y: CGFloat
    internal var f: ()->()
    internal let w: CGFloat = 60
    internal let h: CGFloat = 60

    private let width = -1366/2
    private let height = -1024/2

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.animate.toggle()
            if self.color == Color.green {
                self.color = Color.white
            }
            else {
                self.color = Color.green
                self.f()
            }
        }, label: {
            Ellipse()
                .fill(self.color)
                .scaleEffect(self.animate ? 1.2 : 1)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut)

        }).position(x: self.x + self.w/2, y: self.y + self.h/2)
            .frame(width: self.w, height: self.h, alignment: .center)
            .offset(CGSize(width: self.width, height: self.height))

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to initialize your `CustomView` with the wrong types (`Double` instead of `CGFloat`).

Your `CustomView` initializer looks like this:

```swift
init(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, f: () -> Void)
```

And you call it using the `showTargets` tuple values, which is:

```swift
(id: Int, state: Bool, x: Double, y: Double)
```

So when you do this:

```swift
CustomView(x: item.x, y: item.y, f: {})
```

You are providing `Double` values (for x and y) instead of `CGFloat`. As the cast from `Double` to `CGFloat` cannot be implicit, you need to do it explicitly:

```swift
CustomView(x: CGFloat(item.x), y: CGFloat(item.y), f: {})
```

Comment: Fixed it thanks! Very cryptic error messages and btw. in other cases I didn't need to "cast" to CGFloat

Comment: Super helpful! Thank you!